# Entity Framework Code First : Two DbContext and one database initializers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two `DbContext` in my Project : `ApplicationDbContext` for `ApplicationUser` model (inherited from ASP.NET Identity `IdentityUser` class) and `EFDbContext` for all other models.

They use one database.

I created two database initializers for each of context:

```
 public class ApplicationDbInitializer : 
     DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ApplicationDbContext>
 {
     protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
     {
        // add Admin role and user

        ... code here
        //
        base.Seed(context);
     }
}
```

And

```
 public class EFDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<EFDbContext>
 {
        protected override void Seed(EFDbContext context)
        {
        }
 }
```

The problem:

I get such error in App

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Cannot drop database "DatabaseName" because
>   it is currently in use.

I think it tries re-create database using one context initializer but database is in using by another context.

How to deal with such error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the times, using multiple db-contexts for the *same* database is considered as a bad practice. But if you *really* need this, I am quoting the great answer by Ladislav Mrnka from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197754/entity-framework-one-database-multiple-dbcontexts-is-this-a-bad-idea):

> The problem is when you want to use code first to create your database - only single context in your application can do that. The trick for this is usually one additional context containing all your entities which is used only for database creation. Your real application contexts containing only subsets of your entities must have database initializer set to null.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I'm using two contexts based on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20028146/models-applicationdbcontext-for-all-models-in-an-asp-net-mvc-5-application